# Modelling a FSA in JAVA with a Strategy pattern instead of a State pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns, state-machine, strategy-pattern, state-pattern

*[edit: added exception handling for non-existing transitions at each state]*

I figured out this way of modelling a finite state automaton in Java.

The more pruning unnecessary or redundant classes, the more I found that the State pattern wasn't required at all. Instead, a proper **Strategy** pattern seems to do the job quite nicely.

[image: classes diagram]

The following Java classes represent the FSA of a Gate (state diagram below):

```
/**
 *
 * @author Anton Maria Prati
 */

public class GateFSA {

    GateStateBehaviour stateBehaviour = new ShutGateStateBehaviour();

    String getState(){
        return stateBehaviour.getState();
    }

    void honk() throws Exception{
        transition(GateEvent.HONK);
    }

    void stay() throws Exception{
        transition(GateEvent.STAY);
    }

    void alarm() throws Exception{
        transition(GateEvent.ALARM);
    }

    void transition(GateEvent event){
        System.out.print(getState());
        System.out.print(" -" + event + "-> ");

        GateStateBehaviour nextBehaviour = stateBehaviour.transition(event);
    if (nextBehaviour == null)
        throw new Exception("Illegal transition from this state. ");
    else
        stateBehaviour = nextBehaviour;

        System.out.println(getState());
    }
}

interface GateStateBehaviour{
    public GateStateBehaviour transition(GateEvent event);
    public String getState();
}

class ShutGateStateBehaviour implements GateStateBehaviour {

    @Override
    public GateStateBehaviour transition(GateEvent event) { 
        GateStateBehaviour nextBehaviour = null;
        if (event == GateEvent.HONK)
            nextBehaviour = new RisingGateStateBehaviour();
        if (event == GateEvent.ALARM)
            nextBehaviour = new OpenGateStateBehaviour();
        return nextBehaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return "SHUT";
    }

}

class OpenGateStateBehaviour implements GateStateBehaviour {

    @Override
    public GateStateBehaviour transition(GateEvent event) { 
        GateStateBehaviour nextBehaviour = null;
        if (event == GateEvent.HONK || event == GateEvent.STAY)
            nextBehaviour = new DescendingGateStateBehaviour();
        else if (event == GateEvent.ALARM)
            nextBehaviour = new ShutGateStateBehaviour();
        return nextBehaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return "OPEN";
    }

}

class DescendingGateStateBehaviour implements GateStateBehaviour {

    @Override
    public GateStateBehaviour transition(GateEvent event) { 
        GateStateBehaviour nextBehaviour = null;
        if (event == GateEvent.HONK)
            nextBehaviour = new RisingGateStateBehaviour();
        else if (event == GateEvent.STAY)
            nextBehaviour = new ShutGateStateBehaviour();
        return nextBehaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return "DESCENDING";
    }

}

class RisingGateStateBehaviour implements GateStateBehaviour {

    @Override
    public GateStateBehaviour transition(GateEvent event) { 
        GateStateBehaviour nextBehaviour = null;
        if (event == GateEvent.HONK)
            nextBehaviour = new DescendingGateStateBehaviour();
        else if (event == GateEvent.STAY)
            nextBehaviour = new OpenGateStateBehaviour();
        return nextBehaviour;
    }

    @Override
    public String getState() {
        return "RISING";
    }

}

enum GateEvent {
    HONK,
    STAY,
    ALARM;
}
```

State diagram:
[image: FSM diagram]

Main() method, with non-existing transitions handling (unexpected event at given state):

```
try {
        GateFSA gate = new GateFSA();
        gate.transition(GateEvent.HONK);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.HONK);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.STAY);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.HONK);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.STAY);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.ALARM);
        gate.transition(GateEvent.STAY);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(ex);
    }
```

Output:
[image: OUTPUT]

Why would I to prefer a State Pattern over the design above? Any criticism or comment would be greatly appreciated.